# Is this grammatically correct: finding the subject

Tags: grammaticality

It's hard for a non-native English speaker to figure out what is the subject in the following sentence. Is "a different approach" is the subject of the whether phrase? Then, it should have been "whether a different approach to delivering the needed capabilities **is** in order?"? Considering the context, it seems "the needed capabilities" should be the subject.

> Because we have already spent the money to deliver a “legacy” system, we assume that we have to keep spending money on its continued existence. But why? **Shouldn’t we be deciding whether the incremental spending is worthwhile in itself, or *whether a different approach to delivering the needed capabilities are in order*?** Even if we are just “fixing” or “maintaining” the system?

Comment: That phrase is simply wrong. It should definitely be "is in order". Probably the writer  accepted the naive advice of an automatic grammar checker.

Comment: So you're asking about the subordinate subject(s). The subordination consists of a coordination of two interrogatives: ["whether **the incremental spending** is worthwhile in itself], or [whether **a different approach to delivering the needed capabilities** is in order]. Brackets enclose the subordinate clauses, and their subjects are in bold. "Whether" is just a subordinator.

Answer (score 8):

You are correct that the subject and verb do not agree. It should be: **a new approach... *is* in order.**

The subject of the clause is "a new approach," and the conjugated form of the verb *to be* is "is." The author likely got confused by the plural object "capabilities" directly preceding the verb.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helps a lot.

Comment: This quite a common error by native English speakers. It's so common that I've seen some attempts to make systematize as part of an informal grammar.

Answer (score 4):

While @randomhead has correctly told you that the singular agreement is required, I disagree that *a different approach* is the subject.

The subject of the clause is the whole noun phrase *a different approach to delivering the needed capabilities*. *To delivering the needed capabilities* functions as a complement of "approach", so it is also part of the noun phrase.

The number (singular/plural) of a noun phrase is dependent on its head. The head of the noun phrase in question is "approach", which is singular, so the singular agreement (that is, "is") is required.

Comment: I'd say the matrix subject is "we". "Whether the incremental spending is worthwhile in itself, or whether a different approach to delivering the needed capabilities are in order" is a subordinate interrogative clause.

Comment: @BillJ I'm referring to the subject of the subordinate interrogative clause, which is _a different approach to delivering the needed capabilities_, isn't it?

Comment: OK. The subordination consists of a coordination of two interrogatives: ["whether **the incremental spending** is worthwhile in itself], or [whether **a different approach to delivering the needed capabilities** is in order].

Comment: Thanks all. It's all clear now.